# Publishing Blazor Server Side Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, deployment, blazor-server-side

I am creating a server-side Blazor application with .NET 5.0. I have an SQL Database stored on one of our company drives which my application connects to. My machine is the server for the database.

Whenever I publish the application through Visual Studio to a folder on our company shared drive, the application .exe file will run and provide me with a link to `http://localhost:5000` and `https://localhost:5001` (See image 1)

The issue is whenever another member from our team tests out the application, they are not provided with `https://localhost:5001` (See image 2)

[image: My command prompt upon running .exe]

[image: Team members command prompt upon running .exe]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: HTTPS requires a certificate. I imagine that you have Visual Studio's development certificate installed in your machine and that's why you have the HTTPS endpoint. You most likely need a certificate for the app itself as ASP.NET Core apps are not meant to be distributed like that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Agreed, however I haven't been able to find any resources for obtaining a certificate for the app, any ideas where I could find some?
Also if you have recommendations for better ways to deploy an asp.net core app I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: Normally I'd use letsencrypt, but those certificates are for servers, not for people copying the app to their machines (they would each need a certificate). Any reason you can't deploy the app to a single machine/server and the users test it from there?

Comment: Our company doesn't have any specific machines or servers to deploy the app too, only shared company drives, thus my machine is acting as the server. Plus there isn't any $$$ to be spent on my project :/ Gotta use what I have

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested to test the app from your machine take a look at ngrok https://ngrok.com/

You can use the extension available for Visual studio that is super easy to use, just a click and you'll be able to share your apps to everyone.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions

Comment: I checked out ngrok and got the error, "dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." Would it be safe to assume my work pc is simply unable to allow remote connections?

Comment: Check your firewall settings